# IIS Hosting - error 503 (service unavailable)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Help me good people. l developed an asp.net mvc web app. l have tried everything but l can't access my web from an outside IP address on local network. The web is running on local host. l am using a USB network card, 10 mbps on the IIS server since my 1gig local port malfunctioned. The IIS server is on windows 10.

1)I did setup my IIS server with the binding as follows:
Type: http, Host Name:citycouncilpark.com, Port:8086 IP Address:10.15.8.8
2)I configured the incoming rule for port 8086 on the firewall
3)My applicationhost from the Documents\IISExpress\config folder








**I ALSO TRIED:  (NOT WORKING)
4)l did run cmd as administrator and typed
a)netsh http add iplisten 10.15.8.8
b)netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:8086/ user=Everyone
5)In my System32\Drivers\etc, l edited the hosts file as follows:
10.15.8.8     citycouncilpark.com
6)From my android phone, l tried:
http://10.15.8.8:8086
l always get the response: Service Unavailable (HTTP Error 503)
(The system is running on visual studio 2017)

Comment: NT Event logs should give more (accurate) information about the problem. My bet would be permissions. IIS is (by default) configured to use `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ ` for a good reason. Anything in a `[username]\documents\ ` is risky to allow from outside.  If you copy/move your stuff into the `.\inetpub\wwwroot\ ` folder, does it work?